# Consider a query to find details of research fields where the first two parts of the ID are D and 2 and the last part is one character (digit)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

The ID of research fields have three parts, each part separated by a period.

Consider a query to find the details of research fields where the first two parts of the ID are D and 2, and the last part is a single character (digit).

IDs like D.2.1 and D.2.3 are in the query result whereas IDs like D.2.12 or D.2.15 are not.

The SQL query given below does not return the correct result. Explain the reason why it does not return the correct result and give the correct SQL query.

```
select *
from field
where ID like 'B.1._';
```

I have no idea why it doesnt work.
Anyone can help on this? Many thanks

Comment: Maybe because a `B` <> `D`. `1` <> `2` for starters.

Comment: Do you know what character '_' does when used in LIKE condition?

Comment: "Explain the reason why it does not return the correct result and give the correct SQL query."  - any more commands?

Answer (score 0):

> D.2.1 and D.2.3 are in the query result whereas IDs like D.2.12 or D.2.15 are not.

An underscore matches any single character in a `LIKE` filter so `B.1._` is looking for the start of the string followed by a `B` character followed by a `.` character then a `1` character then a `.` character then any single character then the end of the string.

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   field
WHERE  ID like 'B.1._%';
```

The `%` will match any number of characters (including zero) until the end of the string and the preceding underscore will enforce that there is at least one character after the period.

Comment: "and the last part is **one character**" How do you get from there to your answer?

Comment: @mathguy "D.2.1 and D.2.3 are in the query result whereas IDs like D.2.12 or D.2.15 are not."

Comment: @mathguy After reading the OP twice, the post is inconsistent but this answer appears likely to be correct.

Comment: @MT0 - YES, that is part of the REQUIREMENT. That extra sentence is there for illustration. Do you see where the requirement is to look for D as the first part, but the OP (**and you**) searches/search for B?

Comment: How about I want to get D rather than B answer? Any clue for this? I tried using regex expression but it doesnt work either.

Comment: @HansLeow Put your cursor after the `B` character in the SQL statement, press the `backspace` key then press the `D` key.

Comment: But i got D.2.12 and D.2.15, I only want D.2.(single digit) rather than two digit

Comment: @HansLeow If you read my associated comments (or [**the documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52142)) then you will know that an underscore matches any single character and a percent sign matches zero-or-more characters. You can use these to get what you want - so if you only want a single character then only use an underscore!

Comment: @MT0 I used the query
select *
from field
where ID Like 'D.2._';     

and I didnt get any data... it says no row detected even there is D.2.1 Data